# How to disable headphone jack in Android

Tags: headphones, headphone-jack

I want to completely disable headphone jack in Android 10 without using 3rd party app.
I want to disable headphone jack and use headphones with USB Type-C to 3.5mm jack connector via usb instead.

Comment: i have edited your question, please feel free to revert if i got your goal wrong. it should be sufficient if you restrict google play services access, did you check android settings for headphone jack permissions? did you check usb settings when usb headphones connected? there is also some usb settings in developer options